# libncurses.so.6()(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-client

Tags: centos, mysql

I have been trying to install `mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm` on `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611` and the RPM complain about `libncurses.so.6()(64bit)`

`rpm -Uvh mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm`

```
warning: mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libncurses.so.6()(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.fc25.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.fc25.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.fc25.x86_64
        libtinfo.so.6()(64bit) is needed by mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.fc25.x86_64
```

-

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
Derived from Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.3 (Source)
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using a build for Fedora 25, while you're working on CentOS7. I'd suggest that you download releases for RHEL. To set up everything, you need to download:

```
mysql-community-client-5.7.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-common-5.7.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-libs-5.7.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
mysql-community-server-5.7.17-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

First install `common`, then `libs`, then `client` and so on.

CentOS/RHEL work with `stable` packages, while Fedora uses the newest releases.